# Do I need to establish another database connection in every function defined?

Tags: php, sql

Let's create a very simple example file:

`index.php`:

```
<?php

$connection = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'user', 'pass', 'db');
// connection established successfully

echo 'doing something here for like 500 lines of code';

include('functions.php');
echo countCTR(12, 15);

?>
```

Now, the problem is in `functions.php`:

```
<?php

function countCTR($input1, $input2){
   /* in this function I need my database connection ($connection)
      which was established already in index.php before this
      file was included. however, the $connection isn't open
      inside this function. Do I have to execute mysqli_connect
      inside every function I define?
   */
}

?>
```

Comment: Pass the connection as an additional argument to the function

Comment: @MarkBaker: I believe I've already tried that and it didn't work.

Comment: You have to check if $connection is NULL, if it is, you have to call mysql_connect() inside every method. That is why I suggested mysql_pconnect() call - so you do not have to do the check... As I wrote below, `mysql_pconnect()` will reuse the connection you made previously if exist, if not, it will make another one.

Comment: @MarkBaker: Although in this instance you are passing a _global_ variable. Should you _pass_ a global variable?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You shouldn't.
Just use `global` keyword.

```
function countCTR($input1, $input2){
    global $connection;
}
```

Comment: @Blowski: The OP is using a global variable.

Answer (score 0):

This is explained [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php).

You have two choices: make the $connection global, or pass it in to the methods. I prefer the latter - global variables make me nervous.

To pass the connection in, change the function definition as follows:

```
<?php

function countCTR($input1, $input2, $connection){
   /* in this function I need my database connection ($connection)
      which was established already in index.php before this
      file was included. however, the $connection isn't open
      inside this function. Do I have to execute mysqli_connect
      inside every function I define?
   */
}

?>
```

and invoke it in index.php as follows:

```
echo countCTR(12, 15, $connection);
```

As is mentioned in the comments, it's good practice to think about failure modes, and deal with exceptions in a structured way. The sample code you've posted (and which I have adapted) doesn't check whether the connection is valid before passing it into the function; it also doesn't check whether the connection is still available within the function.

You need to make sure your error handling strategy deals with this - but that's not strictly related to your original question.

Comment: He still has to check if $connection is NULL, and call `mysql_connect()` in the case it is... Or exit with an error if after the first call to mysql_connect() connection cannot be established... Which is also a good alternative.

Comment: @DejanLekic it seems that your opinion (that a developer should check for the connection before every mysql call) is not shared by others.

Comment: @Col.Shrapnel : well, he does not check if it is established or not in the script (as Manus suggested). So how can he be sure if connection is established or not? He either does what Manus wrote, or *has* to check! Any other alternative apart from letting the script fail?

Comment: I think @DejanLekic has a point - but it's not strictly relevant to the question, which is actually about the scope of variables in PHP...have updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: His idea is apparently different. He wants to call connection routine inside of each function. Anyway, it's indeed irrelevant to the problem in question.

Comment: And sorry, I cannot resist from -1ing your answer. Passing $connection looks weird to me. I understands that you never pass it in your code yourself, using a object-wide *global* variable instead. But anyway, passing $connection only for sake of some *superstition*, not by the real need looks weird to me.

Answer (score -1):

Use [mysql_pconnect()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-pconnect.php) function and you will be fine. This function re-uses an already made connection to the database.

**Edit 1**: A certainly better alternative would be to pass the `$connection` to your functions as an argument, as suggested by Mark. I am certainly against using global variables unless *really* necessary. It is rightfully considered a bad programming practice and will just give you headaches.

**Edit 2**: You have three alternatives:

1. Check if $connect is NULL, if it is, exit with error, as suggested by Mensur. If it is not null, then you can reliably use it throughout the rest of the script by passing the $connection as an argument to your functions that use the database.
2. Again, check if $connect is NULL, if it is not, then use it as a global variable in your functions. I am against this approach, see edit 1 for the reason why.
3. Use the `mysql_pconnect()` function, it will create a persistant connect, and any later calls to mysql_pconnect() will use the same connection, if established.

Comment: this is complete offtopic to the question

Comment: Should I? It is *you* came up with the answer *you cannot prove*. (And missed by a mile). An attentive reading of the link you provided should give you enough proof.

Comment: I was reading PHP manuals since '96... And used mysql_pconnect() since it was first introduced in PHP4. So, no need to read it again. If RiMMER establishes a persistent connection in his first script, then later he can safely call mysql_pconnect() again. It is not the best approach (better is to pass the *established* $connection that is *not NULL*), but it will certainly work nicely. If you read the code yourself, you will see that he does not check if $connection is actually established or not... So he has to do it in functions, or, check for null (and you downvoted that suggestion!).

Comment: he can call mysql(i)_connect as well. What's the point in using persistent connection here?

Comment: Sorry buddy, but it seems you don't understand pconnect thing, despite of 16 years of reading manuals. Your (3) is true for the regular connect as well. `Use the mysql_connect() function, and any later calls to mysql_connect() will use the same connection, if established.` there is no use for pconnect and it can solve no the OP's problem.

Answer (score -1):

No you dont. It's enought to create one connection only.
Good idea is to create a database connection in another file and then include it in index.php or any other file.

Example: 
database.php

```
<?php 
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","peter","abc123");
if (!$con)
 {
 die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
 }
?>
```

Example:
index.php

```
<?php include("database.php");?>
```

Hope this helps =)

Comment: This doesn't help -- even when I include the connection to every function, I'm still establishing it over and over again.

Comment: How do you think, is it necessary to read the whole question or just title is enough?

Comment: My bad, sorry... was to fast answering :P

Comment: @Mensur : Your code is actually good. With the approach from the OP, the script should either exit as you suggested, or he has to check for NULLs in every single functions he calls later on, that RELY on that connection!

Answer (score -1):

You can do this using two methods
1. Declaring your $connection link Identifier as global

```
   <?php 
      global $connection = mysql_conect(....); 
      include_once 'yourfile.php';
      $functionReturnValue = CalledFunction( $para1, $para2 );
   ?>
```

Now your yourfile.php will look like

```
   <?php
     function CalledFunetion()
     {
        global $connection;
        // Put rest of the code
     }
   ?>
```

1. Using mysql_pconnect() function

:)